# In the Avengers movie, why did Thor disregard humans by taking the Tesseract with him?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

The Tesseract was an asset of humans (ownership claimed by discovery). It could be used to improve the human wealth of knowledge and to solve the entire human race's energy problems. It had already been used to develop deadly weapons for defense against unfriendly aliens.

When it comes to protecting the Tesseract, I think Ironman and Hulk contributed more than Thor to defeat the Chitauri. By the way, the attackers were more interested in humans than the Tesseract (think about the usefulness of Tesseract-based weapons, again).

Thor wasn't the Tesseract's owner in any way (I am talking about the comics too). But he still took it with him to Asgard. Whether his motive was to harness its power or not, who gave him the right to take the Tesseract with him? Isn't it disregarding humans even when nobody tried to stop him? Why did he take the Tesseract with him?

Comment: -1 for @Sachin Shekhar hangs out here so much that he should know better than to post such a question without spoiler protection somehow!

Comment: @ThePopMachine While I agree, the movie's almost 2 months old. Is a spoiler-protection really necessary?

Comment: @abhiii5459 [It hasn't been out for 2 months](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/releaseinfo).  It's only been out 2-3 weeks here in the US.  The only way you could have seen this movie 2 months ago is if you were in the extremely limited audience who saw the premiere.

Comment: @Keen Oh yeah...I got the dates mixed up :D I just checked the link you posted. My mistake.

Comment: @ThePopMachine If you haven't watched Avengers movie, you shouldn't stumble questions having `avengers` and `movie` tags...

Comment: @SachinShekhar:   "Top questions" is the base URL http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ThePopMachine I mean, you could always ignore those tags. Tags are visible on question list page (just below question title).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Tesseract being on Earth was the only reason the Chitauri were even able to reach Earth, at least in numbers enough to be dangerous.

Thor warns the humans during the course of the movie (multiple times, I think) that the Tesseract is too dangerous for humans to handle.  And that using it has signaled to the rest of the universe that humans are ready for a "higher form of war".

It was simply a matter of SHIELD agreeing that it was better for Thor to safeguard such a powerful artifact in Asgard, rather than turn Earth into an easy target.  We could barely understand it at our current level of technology, after all.

If I recall correctly, it was also the only way for Thor to take Loki back to Asgard.

Comment: Nice answer, but you've simply ignored the advantages of Tesseract and the question: Why didn't Thor wait for permission? After all, the decision was for humans to made..

Comment: And humans did make the decision.  He had the tacit approval of the other Avengers.  They were there when he left and they did not try to stop him from taking it.  Just because they didn't ask for the government's permission doesn't mean no human permission was granted.

Comment: +1 for including the "higher form of war" quote.  Keeping it around was dangerous.

Comment: @SachinShekhar How do you know he didn't wait?  He left during a scene montage, so we don't really know for sure how long it that took...  (Plus, there _was_ that great post-credits scene.  I'd assume SHIELD/whoever else had a say was deliberating during that time)

Comment: @BBlake Government represents big mass, so its required..

Comment: @Izkata In the last, Fury notified council that Tesseract was being taken by that God. Do you still think, he waited and asked for permission?

Comment: @SachinShekhar More specifically, when the council challenged Fury's making the decision to send the Tesseract to Asgard he said "I didn't make it, I just didn't argue with the god that did." The implication from that scene, especially coupled with the friendly send-off from the rest of the team when Thor left was that Fury agreed with Thor's assessment about the Tesseract, and is now practicing some CYA with his superiors.

Comment: @Saiboogu +1 but.... Shouldn't Thor take permission from government? Fury wasn't even in command at that time...

Comment: @SachinShekhar Theoretically, yes. But, Thor had worked with and respected Fury. Given the attempted bombing I'm sure he had no trust of the council or other Earth leadership. It's a common theme in fiction for the outsider to choose their own representative who they feel is more honorable / trustworthy / etc instead of dealing with the established leadership structure.

Comment: @Saiboogu Again +1, but... Isn't it disregard? Who are you to ignore established leadership structure and define your own structure for an entire race?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Yes, in simple terms - Thor disregarded the possible desires of humanity as a whole to take the Tesseract. To the question of why - Izkata explains much of it, and there's the fact that Thor did it with Fury's blessing, a human authority figure whom he respects.

Comment: @SachinShekhar I just took that as Fury getting pissed off at the council  ;)  (IIRC, he does say earlier in the movie that he knows they're not gods, so calling Thor a god at that point...)

Answer (score 12):

The Tesseract was primarily **not** an Earthly(human) asset.

According to the Avengers wiki,
[The Tesseract is an ancient Asgardian artifact of unimaginable power.](http://theavengersmovie.wikia.com/wiki/The_Tesseract)

That's reason enough for him to take it back to Asgard where it rightfully belongs.

And,as Izkata rightly pointed out, he quotes in the movie that it was a sign that indicated that the humans were ready for a higher form of war. So that's another reason Fury and the others **allowed** (although he didn't need permission) him to take it back to Asgard.

Comment: The original source for that wiki link would be the second scene of *Captain America*, when Red Skull finds the cube.

Comment: +1, but as I have remembered... Asgard is also not the original creator/owner of Tesseract. I have almost forgot about that comic, but this thing is in my mind. I don't know who typed it at Wikia.

Comment: @SachinShekhar In the films, it's been presented as a piece of Asgardian tech.  Admittedly, the movies haven't delved much into the origin of it beyond 'it came from Asgard'.

Comment: @Keen Fine... I agree, "It came from Asgard", but it doesn't mean Tesseract is their property. Earth has equal rights over it.

Comment: If your definition of "equal" is "zero",then yes,Earth does have 'equal' rights over the Tesseract

Comment: It's non-logical response. You've stolen statue of liberty to claim your ownership over it. Then, it came to me from you. Why don't I have equal rights as yours over it? Of course, I would not say the same thing with USA (the original owner)..

Comment: I'm sorry; Could you be a bit more lucid with that? I don't quite follow.. :/

Comment: @SachinShekhar Except France gave the US the Statue of Liberty, so there's a legitimacy to the US' ownership.  "Finders keepers" isn't exactly considered a valid grounds for maintaining ownership.

Comment: @Keen Ha.. Ha.. I don't know why Statue of Liberty came to my mind as example.

Answer (score 6):

The Tesseract was once owned by Odin, hence the quote in Captain America:

> It was once the jewel of Odin's treasure room.

It was lost in the last age of worship by man. There are even story lines in the comics alluding to Odin creating the cube itself, so its rightful place is with him. Thor being Odin's son gives him the right to bring it back to Odin.

Answer (score 0):

The humans already had the "mind gem" on Loki's staff (which fell into human hands, and the into Hydra's albeit not known at end of Avengers.

The Tesseract and the Mind Gem would be two of the infinity stones, and for two, or even one to be still on earth would be far too dangerous as other space species wanted those (Thanos etc)

We can quietly assume Asgardians knew about Hydra before we did, why Loki was not hesitant to kill humans or rule them as he already knew of corruption in the ranks of Shield.

Comment: Loki's staff didn't have mind gem. If it was mind gem, Thanos would never give it to Loki.

Comment: @SS Loki's staff did have the mind gem. It is what allowed him to touch people with it and take control of their minds. You see this confirmed in Avengers: Age of Ultron and then later in Avengers: Infinity War, when the gem from the staff is used to "power" Vision's mind and body, and when he is destroyed by Thanos plucking it from his forehead.